# Why am I getting this error in Expo when trying to scan QR code?

Tags: ios, react-native, expo

I get the following error when trying to open my expo project on my iPhone:

> There was a problem running the requested app. It looks like you may be using a LAN URL Make sure your device is on the same network as the server or try using a tunnel

Both my phone and laptop are connected to the same WiFi connection.

I'm not sure what I did wrong. All I have done so far is run the following commands:

```
npm install expo-cli --global

expo init rn-first-app

npm start
```

Answer (score 1):

Does your URL look like this: `exp://192.168.1.2:19000` ?

as opposed to this: `exp://84-gd6.malfuckingfurion.rn-first-app.exp.direct:80`

If so try this:

`expo start --tunnel`

Or this:

`expo start -m tunnel`